# Printing a doubly linked list in reverse only printing first element

Tags: c, list

Writing a function to print a doubly linked list in reverse. The function stops after only printing 7 and does not print the rest of the items in the list. My programs and functions are below.

Edited to include code that didn't paste. Having issues copying and pasting with Putty my apologies.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
        int data;
        struct node *next;
        struct node *prev;
};
typedef struct node node;


void printRev(node* head);
node* removeNode(node* head, int d);
node* insertFront(node* head, int d);
node* insertBack(node* head, int d);
void print(node* head);
int max(node* head);
int min(node* head);
int locInList(node* head, int x);

int main()
{

        node* head = NULL;

        head = insertFront(head, 5);
        head = insertFront(head, 4);
        head = insertBack(head, 6);
        head = insertBack(head, 7);
        print(head);
        printRev(head);

        printf("Max: %d\n", max(head));
        printf("Min: %d\n", min(head));
        printf("locInList 5: %d\n", locInList(head, 5));
        printf("locInList 9: %d\n", locInList(head, 9));

        head = removeNode(head, 6);
        print(head);
        head = removeNode(head, 4);
        print(head);
        head = removeNode(head, 7);
        print(head);


        return 0;
}

void printRev(node* head) {
        node *cur = head;
        node *tmp = NULL;
        if (cur == NULL) {
            return;
        }
        else {
            while(cur->next != NULL) {
                cur = cur->next;
            }
            while(cur != NULL) {
               printf("%d ", cur->data);
               cur = cur->prev; 
            } 
        }
        printf("\n");
}

node* removeNode(node* head, int d)
{

        node *tmp = head->next;
        head->data = head->next->data;
        head->next = tmp->next;
        free(tmp);
        return head;
}

node* insertFront(node* head, int d)
{
        node *tmp = NULL;
        tmp = malloc(sizeof(node));
        tmp->data = d;
        tmp->next = head;
        head = tmp;
        return head;
}

node* insertBack(node* head, int d)
{
        node *tmp = malloc(sizeof(node));

        tmp->data = d;
        tmp->next = NULL;

        if(head == NULL){
                return head;
        }
  }
        else{
        node *end = head;

        while(end->next != NULL){
                end = end->next;
        }
                end->next = tmp;
            }

        return head;


}

void print(node* head)
{

        node *tmp = head;

        while(tmp != NULL){
   printf("%d ", tmp->data);
                tmp = tmp->next;
                        }
        printf("\n");
}

int max (node* head)
{

        int max = head->data;
        node *tmp = NULL;
        tmp = head;


        while(tmp->next != NULL){
                if(tmp->data >= max){
                        max = tmp->data;
                }
                        tmp = tmp->next;
                }
                     }
        return min;
}

int locInList(node* head, int x)
{

        int i = 0;
        node *tmp = NULL;
        tmp = head;

        while(tmp != NULL){
                if(tmp->data == x){
                return i;
                }else{
                i++;
                tmp = tmp->next;
                        }  }
                return -1;

}
```

Expected results are  - 7 6 5 4
Received results are  - 7

Comment: Can you post the code of node structure and insertion function.

Comment: Just did. My apologies. Still getting used to nano and Putty.

Comment: Where are other function definitions??

Comment: `prog.c:99:9: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘else’`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it's a doubly  linked list, you should point your head's back pointer to temp(new inserted one) in the function insertFront. So it should be ;

```
 node* insertFront(node* head, int 
d)
{
    node *tmp = NULL;
    tmp = malloc(sizeof(node));
    tmp->data = d;
    tmp->prev=NULL:
     if(head==NULL)
                return tmp;
     head->prev=tmp;
    tmp->next = head;
    return tmp;
}
```

Similarly in insertBack function take care of making prev pointer point to previous node in the list.

Answer (score 2):

Neither `insertFront` nor `insertBack` set `prev`, which is the root cause of your problem.  (Your reverse iteration loop critically depends on the `prev` pointers having been set correctly.)

Comment: My apologies. Didnt copy the entire code from Putty.

Comment: This could be a comment :(

Comment: @User_Unknown_3458: What's the return value of `insertFront` and `insertBack`?  It looks odd that you keep overwriting `head`.

Comment: return head;   in both insertFront and insertBack functions

Comment: @User_Unknown_3458: Why don't you show us the code for those functions since it's likely the problem is within them.

Comment: Just edited to do so. Thank you. Entire program is posted now.

Comment: @User_Unknown_3458: Neither of those functions sets `prev`, which is the root cause of your problem.

Comment: I am editing my insertFront and insertBack funtctions to set prev but am running into a segmentation fault upon changing the code.

Comment: @User_Unknown_3458: Please post a separate, self-contained question so that we're not chasing a moving target.